# Linux - apply .wim image file to ntfs volume

Tags: partition, opensuse, ntfs-3g

Im trying to apply a .wim image file to a ntfs partition on my SSD. In windows, we would use dism.exe to perform this task, but for linux, seems like wimapply from wimlib can be used for this purpose. below is my SSD partition when checked using Linux-parted tool :

```
Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
1       1049kB  50.0GB  50.0GB  primary  ntfs         type=07
2       50.0GB  150GB   100GB   primary  ntfs         type=07
```

So, the command i used with wimapply was : "wimapply /path/to/wim/file /dev/sdb1". But below is the error message i got :

"[ERROR] wimlib was compiled without support for NTFS-3G, so it cannot apply a WIM image directly to an NTFS volume. ERROR: Exiting with error code 68: The requested operation is unsupported"

i have confirmed that my Linux env has ntfs-3g installed, below is the zypper search ntfs-3g output :

```
S | Name          | Summary                                     | Type
--+---------------+---------------------------------------------+--------
i | libntfs-3g85  | NTFS Support in Userspace -- Library        | package
i | ntfs-3g       | NTFS Support in Userspace                   | package
  | ntfs-3g-devel | Development files and libraries for ntfs-3g | package
```

i cant find much info on google. Can someone please help to advise how to apply a .wim image to a ntfs partition on Linux

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the following taken from the winapply man page holds the key to this problem:

Finally, note that this mode uses libntfs-3g directly, without going through the ntfs-3g(8) driver. Hence, there is no special support for applying a WIM image to a directory on which an NTFS filesystem has been mounted using ntfs-3g(8); you have to unmount it first. There is also no support for applying a WIM image to some subdirectory of the NTFS volume; you can only apply to the root directory.

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: thank you for feedback. i checked with df -h command and confirmed the ntfs volume on my SDD is unmounted. Not sure why still cant apply the wim image.